# What do I do with my 7-month old pitbull who won't stop urinating?

Tags: dogs, behavior

I have a 7 month old pitbull. He's peeing all the time. He pees in his sleep, and every time he walks even if he just came back inside. What do I do?

Comment: Can you add additional information, like if he has been neutered, what kind of training have you done, how often is he allowed outside, etc?

Comment: What do you mean by "What do I do"? You're asking what you should do to stop the urinating?

Comment: Also, is this condition something that's started up recently, or has it always been the case?

Comment: I'm closing this right now. Please add more details about your pet and any steps you've taken (including vet visits) and we can reopen the question.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the vet. It is not normal for a dog to pee in their sleep.

Comment: +1 this is not normal behavior even for a dog that is not yet potty trained. Frequent and seemingly uncontrollable peeing could be a sign of a UTI.

Answer (score 2):

Check with your vet. It could be a UTI, or could also be incontinence. My dog did this too as a puppy (leaking in her sleep), and we determined that she was incontinent. I give her an inexpensive drug to stop it. She is now 10 years old, and the problem has been solved all these years.